# Numerical method for ordinary differential equation with complex coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

In physics, there are a lot of cases of ordinary differential equation with complex coefficients. Or there are cases where solution of ODE with real coefficients is complex number.

What is numerical method for such cases? Can we just use methods used for real-coefficient/real-valued ODE?

Comment: Yes, you can. Algebraic operations work the same.

Comment: There exist some schemes, for example Rosenbrock schemes with complex coefficients, that achieve higher order or have some nice properties when complex arithmetics is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Standard methods for real coefficients will work. In fact, the test method for A-stability usually has solve solving for a timestep to the linear problem with a complex coefficients (simulating complex eigenvalues of the Jacobian). Thus for all of the main methods it's well known what the stability is when you have complex numbers.